# VBA - Change chart line colour

Tags: excel, vba

I've been attempting to get a VBA script that will update chart line colours based on an RGB reference that will change based on a score.

I would also like to understand:

1. How to exclude some sheets from the update
2. How to exclude some series from the update (they always remain grey)

My current script is:

```
Sub UpdateAllChartLines

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ser As Series

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
Set myRed = Worksheets("TextElements").Range("K6")
Set myGreen = Worksheets("TextElements").Range("K7")
Set myBlue = Worksheets("TextElements").Range("K8")
Set myThickness = Worksheets("TextElements").Range("E37")

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        cht.Activate
                With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(myRed, myGreen, myBlue)
                .Format.Line.Weight = myThickness
                 End With
    Next ser
   Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

My issue recently has been that I get a debug error at

```
For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
```

As ever any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what criteria do you want to exclude sheets and series?  What property (eg Name for worksheets) do you want to check before making any changes?  When you get a debug error, what's the error message?

Comment: You need to refer to the Chart property of the ChartObject -->  `For Each ser In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to clarify on what basis you want to exclude things, but something like this should work.

Note there's no need to activate/select anything in order to change it.

```
Sub UpdateAllChartLines()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim clr As Long, sNum

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("TextElements")
        clr = RGB(.Range("K6").Value, .Range("K8").Value, .Range("K8").Value)
        myThickness = .Range("E37").Value
    End With

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "IgnoreThis" Then '<<< can exclude sheets here
            For Each chtObj In sht.ChartObjects
                For Each sNum in Array(5,6,7,8) '<<<edit
                'For Each ser In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection

                        With chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(sNum)
                            .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
                            .Format.Line.Weight = myThickness
                        End With

                'Next ser
                Next sNum
            Next chtObj
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for that code - its broadly working. I want to exclude some series based on the Series name - these are "CountryAverage", "ADM0" and "Forecast_ADM0".

Comment: Also made one little edit - "Next cht" is changed to "Next chtObj"

Comment: When I select the relevant series using Record Macro they are listed as follows:

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).Select

Comment: See my edit above - you can loop over an array of series numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked Tim's response up as the answer, but thought I'd add in my final working script to help anyone in future. I suspect that this could be simplified, but I couldn't get it to work with `ser.name = x OR y OR z Then` Tim's answer also for unknown reasons added markers to the first series on each graph, but this was easily fixed by adding the `.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone` command.

Thanks again to Tim and to everyone else who commented.

J

```
Sub UpdateAllChartLines()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim clr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("TextElements")
        clr = RGB(.Range("K6").Value, .Range("K7").Value, .Range("K8").Value)
        myThickness = .Range("K9").Value
    End With

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" Then '<<< can exclude sheets here
        If sht.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
            For Each chtObj In sht.ChartObjects
                For Each ser In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
                        If ser.Name <> "Series1" Then
                        If ser.Name <> "Series2" Then
                        If ser.Name <> "Series3" Then
                        If ser.Name <> "Series4" Then
                            With ser
                                .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
                                .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                                .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
                                .Format.Line.Weight = myThickness
                                .Format.Glow.Radius = 0
                            End With
                        End If
                        End If
                        End If
                        End If
                Next ser
            Next chtObj
        End If
        End If
    Next sht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```